MYSQL numbering with group by
I have the following table:



title
date
name




title1
2023-01-01
Hans


title1
2023-01-01
Fritz


title1
2023-01-01
Bernd


title1
2023-01-02
Heiner


title1
2023-01-02
Markus


title1
2023-01-02
Mario


title2
2023-01-03
Reiner


title2
2023-01-03
Werner


title2
2023-01-03
Erwin


title2
2023-01-04
Klaus


title2
2023-01-04
Hans


title2
2023-01-04
Joachim


title3
2023-01-05
Matthias


title3
2023-01-05
Uwe


title3
2023-01-05
Sasha


title3
2023-01-06
Kevin


title3
2023-01-06
Sabine


title3
2023-01-06
Maria



I do the following statement:
SELECT title, date
FROM table
GROUP BY title, date
ORDER BY title date


Result is:



title
date




title1
2023-01-01


title1
2023-01-02


title2
2023-01-03


title2
2023-01-04


title3
2023-01-05


title3
2023-01-06



How can I get the following result:



title
date
no




title1
2023-01-01
1


title1
2023-01-02
2


title2
2023-01-03
1


title2
2023-01-04
2


title3
2023-01-05
1


title3
2023-01-06
2



I want to numbering the title 1,2,3 ...
Many thanks for your answers.

What version of mysql you are using ? select version();

I can't work out the logic for the desired outcome - can you?

@P.Salmon each time the title is equal to the previous put no=no+1, each time the title changes no=1

If you're using MySQL 8, you can achieve this by using the window function ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() If you want titles with the same date to receive the same ranking :
SELECT title, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY title ORDER BY date) AS no
FROM mytable
GROUP BY title, date
ORDER BY title, date

